# C.U.S.A.C. - Campaign for the Unionization of Spiders and Crawlers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Let's get together and join the two great peoples (tags) of Spider- and Crawler-kind.  I ran into a question with [crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crawl) (no summary) and decided there must be a better tag in SO.  Sure enough there are many better tags on SO, all so closely related that they should really be joined together.  So brethren, I ask you to vote (only if you have legal residence in [web-crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler)) on joining the orphaned individuals of Spider- and Crawler-kind under the benevolent oversite, err, communal support of [web-crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler).

*OOC: Let's get the tag synonym voting feature working on a practical level.  There seems to be some good suggestions that languish a bit.*

---

[web-crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler) (x2481) - [Vote Now](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-crawler/synonyms)

> A Web crawler is a computer program that browses the World Wide Web in a methodical, automated manner or in an orderly fashion. Other terms for Web crawlers are ants, automatic indexers, bots, Web spiders, Web robots, or – especially in the FOAF community – Web scutters.

**Synonyms Needing Approval:**

- **3** [crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crawler) (x577)

  > Crawler or web crawler is a bot program that automatically walks through World Wide Web sites. Crawlers are important part of search engines.
- **2** [crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crawl) (x173)

  > A Web crawler is a computer program that browses the World Wide Web in a methodical, automated manner or in an orderly fashion.
- **2** [crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crawling) (x265)

  > Crawling is the process of browsing the Web in automated and methodical manner.

**Also Needs Suggesting:**

- [spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spider) (x258)

  > Synonym for web-crawler tag. Somebody please synonym it (I lack the rep in web-crawler tag)

**Existing synonyms:**

- [webcrawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcrawling)
- [webspiders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webspiders)
- [web-spiders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-spiders)

Comment: +1 nice question, I'm not crawling enough to vote on the synonyms though....

Comment: `status-complete`: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all&search=web-crawler!

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you to those that contributed (now and with the previous suggestions).

Comment: What about merging [tag:screen-scraping] and [tag:web-scraping]? They both appeared in the Related Tags section for web-craler

Comment: I was noticing those too.  I haven't taken an indepth look, but my initial reaction is that scraping is something that is probably not unique to web crawlers, though web crawlers do scraping.

Comment: @wumm Sorry, but I don't see any reason for your change.  If you can come up for a good reason why the title of this question should NOT be as I have written it, then please comment.  The tags and body of the question make it clear as to the intention of the post.

Comment: @JasonMArcher The title is simply meaningless and nonsense. Why to use a newly invented abbreviation for merging tags? In "Hot Meta Posts" it does not make any sense if it says "C.U.S.A.C. - Campaign for the Unionization of Spiders and Crawlers". I first had no idea what the question was about (I thought of anything but not of a simple tag merging), and that's the sense of a title, telling people what they have to except

Comment: @wumm It's pretty obvious. Unionize = merge. Spiders and crawlers are synonyms. Is it really so much of a leap? :P

Comment: @eddie_cat It's simply a bad title. You are thinking of a point were you already know what this questions is about. But I'm telling you what I really thought when I saw the title with just one eye. But if you all love that "very creative" title then keep it.

Comment: It is a Campaign (work in an organized and active way toward a particular goal) to Unionize (bring together) Spiders (there are many different tags, so I refer to the group) and Crawlers (ditto).  Yes I wrote the title in a creative way.  TO GET ATTENTION TO IT.  And it worked, we made SO better in about 15 minutes.

Comment: @JasonMArcher, plus, when it comes to meta posts about tags, you are unofficially _required_ to make it a creative title.

Answer (score 8):

Per comments, this is now **Completed**.

Would a mod please mark this **status-complete**?